# In Javascript all objects have prototypes, except for the base object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

for clarifying, there is an interview question's answer on github that says :

> All objects have prototypes, except for the base object. The base
> object is the object created by the user, or an object that is created
> using the new keyword. The base object has access to some methods and
> properties, such as .toString. This is the reason why you can use
> built-in JavaScript methods! All of such methods are available on the
> prototype. Although JavaScript can't find it directly on your object,
> it goes down the prototype chain and finds it there, which makes it
> accessible for you.

I've read this answer several times, but unfortunately it did not help me, could anyone explain it in a more understandable way?.

Also the link to answer is [here](https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions#:%7E:text=14.%20All%20object%20have%20prototypes.).

Comment: The result of `Object.create(null)` does not have a prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of objects you'll encounter ultimately inherit from `Object.prototype`. This includes built-in objects and objects created with object literal syntax, among many others.

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype);
```

A very few objects, including `Object.prototype` itself, do not inherit from anything. This will only occur if the object is explicitly created with `Object.create(null)`.

```js
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null,
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(null)) === null
);
```

Comment: Also, an object created explicitly with no prototype is a pain to deal with, because (for one example) it has no `.toString()` or `.valueOf()` methods available.